# WPF NumberTextBox Allowing Decimals

Tags: wpf

I am having an issue with NumberTextBox. Below is the xaml code.

```
<cc:NumberTextBox
                    Margin="5,0,5,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"
                    Style="{StaticResource TextBox_Default}"
                    TabIndex="25"
                    IsDecimalAllowed="True"
                    Text="{Binding ProductQuantity, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, StringFormat={}{0:#.##}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

It should allow user to enter **only 2 digits** after the decimal. I tried to use StringFormat but it i snot working.

Example: 23.65567 it should allow user to enter only 23.65

Any suggestions to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, NumberTextBox is not a standard part of WPF. you should tag whatever library you are using for that element. then you will find more help here.

[This link goes to a page where you can write your own NumberTextBox](http://www.wpfsharp.com/tag/numbertextbox/). As for digit limiting, just test for the "dot" and allow two more key-downs.

[This link is an open source collection for numeric input control](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Wpf.NumericInput)